# Fetching data from event table in zoho crm

Tags: events, fetch, crm, zoho

I am new in zoho crm. How can I fetch all data from event table in zoho CRM? Is there any api? Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use https://crm.zoho.com/crm/private/xml/Events/getRecords?authtoken=Auth Token&scope=crmapi to get list of events.